# List of valid users on Android system

Tags: android

I am debugging an application on a rooted [B&N Nook Glowlight](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/p/nook-glowlight-barnes-noble/1114959612). The app runs fine on a rooted [B&N Nook SimpleTouch](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/p/nook-simple-touch-with-glowlight-barnes-noble/1108046469) but crashes on the Glowlight.

It seems that the paths in use on the Glowlight have the wrong users assigned to them. **How can I get a list of valid users on Android?** On a standard *NIX I would just `cat /etc/passwd` but that file does not exist on this Android system.

I suspect that both devices are Android 2.1. If there is a command that will tell me this for sure, please let me know. The both devices are running Linux kernel 2.6.29 (armv71).

**Edit:** Note that I mean a list of system users, such as `root`, and `app_12`. This is how Unix traditionally handles separation of privileges, and I think is where the problem lies. I don't mean a list of Human user accounts. I'm looking for a CLI command, not an Android API call.

Answer (score 0):

That's available via [AccountManager.getAccounts()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccounts%28%29), if your app has the required permissions to view accounts at all.

From your description, it's possible your app is hardcoding a path that is correct for old Android versions, rather than using a newer, more correct way to get a file's path via Context.getFilesDir().  See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html .

Comment: Thank you chaqke. I'm not looking for a list of human user accounts, but rather Unix system users. I've edited the question to clarify that.